# How to prevent 3 nested MySQL queries from timing out

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all records in t3 where the field names in t2 are missing, but only if they meet a certain record id from t1.

The query for t1:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM t1 WHERE name1 = "XXX" AND user_id = '$id'
```

works fine.

The t2 query:

```
SELECT name2 FROM t2 WHERE record IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t1 WHERE name1 = "XXX" AND user_id = '$id')
```

also works fine, but takes a while.

But the t3 query:

```
DELETE FROM t3 WHERE name3 NOT IN (SELECT name2 FROM t2 WHERE record IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t1 WHERE name1 = "XXX" AND user_id = '$id'));
```

results in "#2006 - MySQL server has gone away"

How to get my query result within reasonable time?

Comment: You may want to look into `JOIN`s instead. However without testing it it would just be guessing. `EXPLAIN` is your friend here

Comment: Looks like I have to hand back the results of the two inner queries to PHP and query t3 separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use join queries instead?

```
select name2, MAX(t1.id) 
from t2
inner join t1
on t2.t1_id = t1.id
where name1="XXX" AND user_id='$id'
```

Comment: Thanks for working out this query for me. It works for t1 and t2, but I still have the problem with t3.

Comment: I think you then need a left / right join where name3 is null.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Great stuff. I will post my final code here later.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare table with records to be deleted instead using sub query - in stored proc or sth.like that.

of course indexes ;)

Comment: "add indexes" in proper places  ;)

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: STEPS:
1. create temp table from select from t1,t2
2. add index to new table
3. delete from t3
4. drop temp table  

I'm doing such trick in huge dayly import table - few milions records. Maybe there is better solution, but it's good and quick in stored prodecure.

Comment: Thanks again! The solution using join seems simpler to me, but I definitely have to look into stored procedures soon.

Comment: it's worth to know procedures, because You can set event to deal with hard queries at night when users are out = without pressure on performance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I see the advantages and I also understand that stored procedures are supported by MySQL since 5.0.